# What programming language?

Tags: visual-studio, programming-languages

I obtain this surce code, but I don't know what is the language and how can I open it. Can I open it using visual studio? (no project file is found)

[image]

Comment: Looks like VB6. You need Visual Studio 6 for that...

Comment: Can i use Visual Studio 10 ?

Comment: No. You can't use Visual Studio 2003/2005/2008/2010/2012 with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are Visual Basic 6 files, you'll need to have and old version of Visual Studio to open it trough the importer, because newer versions don't support pre-.NET versions.

You can do it in Visual Studio 2008 or prior acorrding to this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260644.aspx

Comment: I would say that the .NET versions will try to _upgrade_ the VB6 files. This is not the same as just opening them.

Answer (score 2):

Old school VB. Pre .NET. Open the VBP in Visual Studio 6.0. If you open it anything newer it'll try to upgrade it, and chances are you'll have many compilation errors. .NET and 6.0 are drastically different. If you have MSDN you still have access to older versions of Visual Studio or VB. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Visual Basic to me. See [here for file types used there](http://www.hitmill.com/programming/vb/filetypes.html)

To be more exact, you would need to provide some sample content. :)